# Pass a list of columns to data.table’s CJ as a vector

Tags: r, data.table, cross-join

I have the following code:

```
main_cols <- c('num', 'let')
dt <- data.table(num = 1:5, let = letters[1:5])
dt

new_dt <- dt[CJ(num = num
                , let = let
                , unique = TRUE)
             , on = main_cols
             ]
head(new_dt, 10)
```

The thing is: I want to pass the columns to cross-join on as a vector. How do I “unpack” `main_cols` inside the `CJ` function? Thanks.

Comment: Maybe with a `do.call`? Can you show sample input and expected output?

Comment: I edited to provide a reproducible code that gives sample input/output.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you'll want to use `do.call`, as @AnandaMahto suggested:

```
m = dt[, do.call(CJ, .SD), .SDcols=main_cols]
dt[m, on=main_cols]
```

---

You could also create `m` this way:

```
m = do.call(CJ, dt[,main_cols,with=FALSE])
```

If you have repeating values in the columns, use the `unique` option to `CJ`:

```
m = dt[, do.call(CJ, c(.SD, unique=TRUE)), .SDcols=main_cols]
# or 
m = do.call(CJ, c(dt[,main_cols,with=FALSE], unique=TRUE))
```

Comment: Can you explain why the need for `dt[m, on=main_cols]` which produce the same result as `m`? Thx.

Comment: @fishtank In the OP's example, the two results are the same. If `dt` had some other columns besides those in `main_cols`, it would be different. Also, if some pairs of values in `m` either (i) did not appear in `dt` or (ii) appeared in multiple rows of `dt`, it would also be different (I think). Oh, forgot to mention: `dt[m,on=main_cols]` is a merge.

Comment: @Frank Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @Frank, thanks for the `unique` addendum. I do indeed have repeating values in one of the columns, and I was banging my head against the wall (I was passing `list`, not a vector of arguments) until I looked at your code.