# Complete with all combinations after counting on data.table

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I have data with some columns as factor and some as character. I want to count all combinations and write a function with data.table syntax

```
# Load libraries

library(dplyr)
library(data.table)

# Create data

i_df = iris %>%
  filter(Species != 'virginica') %>%
  mutate(
    len   = ifelse(Sepal.Length > 6, 'large', 'tiny'),
    width = ifelse(Sepal.Width > 3, 'thick', 'thin'),
    color = ifelse(Species == 'setosa', 'green', 'red')
  ) %>% 
  mutate(
    len   = factor(len, levels = c('large', 'med_len', 'tiny')),
    width = factor(width, levels = c('thick', 'med_width', 'thin'))
  )
```

This would be an example of my function:

```
myfun = function(d, g, mode) {
  
  # Convert to data.table  
  setDT(d)
  
  # Counting
  res = d[, .N, by = g]
  
  # Complete combinations
  setkeyv(res, cols = g)
  
  res = switch(
    mode,
    manual = {
      res[CJ(levels(d$Species), levels(d$len), levels(d$width), unique(d$color)),]
    },
    auto = {
      m = res[, do.call(CJ, c(.SD, unique = TRUE)), .SDcols = g]
      res[m, on = g]
    }
  )
  
  # Add zero when NA
  res[is.na(res)] = 0
  
  # Return
  return(res)
  
}
```

How to run:

```
g_tmp = c('Species', 'len', 'width', 'color')

myfun(d = i_df, g = g_tmp, mode = 'manual')
myfun(d = i_df, g = g_tmp, mode = 'auto')
```

As you can see, I'm using `setkeyv` and not `setkey`, because I need use character vector `g`. But when complete with `CJ`, I cannot get it working with character vector input `mode = 'auto'`. There, indicate all factor levels for factors and all present colors `unique` for all character columns. As you can see, with `mode = 'manual'`, 54 rows are returned, and with `mode = 'auto'`, non-present factor levels are not returned, and result is 16 rows.

I've found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34750437/pass-a-list-of-columns-to-data-table-s-cj-as-a-vector) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49013403/data-table-cj-with-string-as-input) but I cannot get it working when I have a mix of factor and character columns

As some colums are factors with some non-present levels, `unique` is not good here, only for the character columns

Comment: Related: [Empty factors in "by" data.table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18866796/empty-factors-in-by-data-table#18866796)

Comment: The "_Do not preserve column classes_" is unrelated to `by` dropping unused levels, but is a result of your next step: `table(i_dt[,..g]) %>% as.data.table()`. See also issues for a discussion: [Grouping could include unused factor levels while computing `j` (like `tapply` does)](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/562); [Should grouping by a factor always return a row for every level of the factor (no dropping missing levels)?](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/4421)

Comment: Thanks, I saw those links before. With one of them, I discovered the base::table function

Comment: After thinking about it, your were right. I've simplified the question to the main one, how to write it as a general function

Comment: @Archymedes what do you want to do (exactly)? You described your problem but what you expect is not really clear (in my opinion). Why don't you add the expected output?

Comment: @B. Christian Kamgang, I see. I've edited to explain the resulting problem. Entering manually all factor levels and unique, I have all combinations. With mode = 'auto', non-present factor levels are not completed

Comment: I have posted one possible solution. Let me know if it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one possible way to solve your problem. Note that the argument `with=FALSE` in the `data.table` context allows to select the columns using the standard `data.frame` rules. In the example below, I assumed that the columns used to compute all combinations are passed to `myfun` as a *character* vector.
Keep in mind that no columns in your dataset should be named *gcases*. `.EACHI` in `by` allows to perform some operation for each row in `i`.

```
myfun = function(d, g) {
  # get levels (for factors) and unique values for other types. 
  fn <- function(x) if(is.factor(x)) levels(x) else unique(x)
  gcases <- lapply(setDT(d, key=g)[, g, with=FALSE], fn)
  
  # count based on all combinations
  d[do.call(CJ, gcases), .N, keyby=.EACHI]
}
```

Comment: That's it. Thanks a lot